# How to append CSV files using unix Commands when the number of columns are different for different files

Tags: shell, unix, csv, append

I have few thousands of csv files each with different set of column headers. I am appending them currently using python pandas. I would like to know if there is an efficient way to append those files in UNIX.

For Example.

```
CSV1:

Column1,Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5
1,aaa,bbb,0,NULL
2,aa1,bb1,,NULL

CSV2:

Column1,Column2, Column6, Column7, Column8
1,aaa,xyz,0,NULL
2,aa1,zy1,test-2,NULL


Required Output

Column1,Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5,Column6, Column7, Column8
1,aaa,bbb,0,NULL,,,
2,aa1,bb1,,NULL,,,,
1,aaa,,,,xyz,0,NULL
2,aa1,,,,zy1,test-2,NULL
```

The values should be aligned against appropriate column names when appending two files are done and the header of the second file should be appended to the final output header appropriately with no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$0;next}($1$2 in a){x=$1$2;$1=$2="";gsub(/^,*/,"");print a[x]","$0}' file1 file2
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp2
Column1,Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5
1,aaa,bbb,0,NULL
2,aa1,bb1,,NULL
> 
> 
> cat temp
Column1,Column2, Column6, Column7, Column8
1,aaa,xyz,0,NULL
2,aa1,zy1,test-2,NULL
> 
> 
> awk -F, -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$0;next}($1$2 in a){x=$1$2;$1=$2="";gsub(/^,*/,"");print a[x]","$0}' temp2 temp
Column1,Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8
1,aaa,bbb,0,NULL,xyz,0,NULL
2,aa1,bb1,,NULL,zy1,test-2,NULL
>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. But it does not produce the desired output. It concats the values of two rows on the Id values 1 and 2. Rather, I would like to see different rows for each of the rows in 2 different csv files but they have to make sure the additional columns are appropriately aligned in the final output

Answer (score 0):

`join -t , -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1 -o 1.2 -o 1.3 -o 1.4 -o 1.5 -o 2.3 -o 2.4 -o 2.5 CSV1 CSV2`

seems a better way

& also you could use `cut` as the following

`cat CSV2 | cut -f 1,3,4,5 -d , > tmp1`

`join -t ',' -j 1  CSV1 tmp1`

Comment: Can you please help me understand what the first join command does? For the suggestion using cut, I do not know the column fields before hand to cut them respectively.

Comment: What if do not know before hand the number of columns in each of the file?

Comment: `-t` means seperator by `,`; `-1 1` means join the file1's first field to `-2 1` the file2's first field; `-o` means output, `1.1` means the file 1's first field; so does the following

Comment: for if do not know the number of clolumns~ well, maybe you could join the file and search for some method to `remove the duplicated field` by `awk` command; or just write a simple shell to generate that list. :)